# how to send email in snowpark (snowflake python worksheet)

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the following code to send email in snowflake python worksheet on execution I getting the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): Worksheet, line 13, in main File "snowflake/snowpark/session.py", line 2349, in call return self._call(sproc_name, *args, statement_params=statement_params) File "snowflake/snowpark/session.py", line 2367, in _call validate_object_name(sproc_name) File "snowflake/snowpark/_internal/utils.py", line 187, in validate_object_name raise SnowparkClientExceptionMessages.GENERAL_INVALID_OBJECT_NAME(name) snowflake.snowpark.exceptions.SnowparkInvalidObjectNameException: (1500): The object name 'SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL'`

`session.call(f"SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL('Email_INT_OBJ',{DISTRIBUTION_DETAILS},{MESSAGE_HEADER_UPD},{MESSAGE_BODY_UPD})")`

Notification Integration:

`CREATE NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION Email_INT_OBJ TYPE=EMAIL ENABLED=TRUE;`

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Is there an error message and what is it? Please also update your question with the definition of your notification integration

Comment: Have you verified your email address in Snowflake? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/email-stored-procedures#label-email-notification-verify-address

Comment: @NickW: Hi Nick, I have verified the email its working in SQL worksheet, but its throwing error in python worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [session.call](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.call)
>
> SIGNATURE
>
> Session.call(sproc_name: str, *args: Any, statement_params: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None, log_on_exception: bool = False) → Any

---

Simple copying and pasting code from SQL Worksheet to Python Worksheet will not work.

Option 1:

```
session.call(f"SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL('Email_INT_OBJ',{DISTRIBUTION_DETAILS},
                                 {MESSAGE_HEADER_UPD},{MESSAGE_BODY_UPD})")

=>

session.call("SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL", "Email_INT_OBJ",
             DISTRIBUTION_DETAILS, MESSAGE_HEADER_UPD, MESSAGE_BODY_UPD)
```

Option 2:

Using `session.sql(...).collect()`:

```
session.sql(f"CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL('Email_INT_OBJ',{DISTRIBUTION_DETAILS},{MESSAGE_HEADER_UPD},{MESSAGE_BODY_UPD})").collect()
```